# echo does not evaluate variables when reading from text file

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

My requirement is to echo contents of a text file line by line.

Content of text file also contains some variables. So, it is expected, that echo command will display value for those variables. Please find below modified code listing:

- `reader.bat`:

  ```
  @echo off

  set key=value
  echo Check key : %key%

  for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (test.template) do echo %%A
  ```
- `test.template`:

  ```
  Expected data for key : %key%
  ```

**Expected output is:**

```
Check key : value
Expected data for key : value
```

**Actual output is:**

```
Check key : value
Expected data for key : %key%
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
...
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (test.template) do CALL echo %%A
```

You need the data to be evaluated, not jost regurgitated.